# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid - loop on selected rows after button click event

Tags: oracle, apex

I have Interactive Grid named InterfaceGrid, with many columns, but currently I  consider only this two: ID as text, and Value as select list.
I would like to select few rows (by checkboxes from left grid site), and - after clicking new button - UpdateButton - perform action looping selected items.

I tried some code, but how to loop on selected rows? As I undestand, I can not use this.data.selectedRecords while fire event from button, not grid event, and I must somehow loop over model variable?

```
var model = apex.region("InterfaceGrid").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid").model;

var id;
var value;

if(this.data != null){
    for ( i = 0; i < this.data.selectedRecords.length; i++ ) { 
    if(this.data.selectedRecords[i]!= null){
        product_wizard_code= model.getValue(this.data.selectedRecords[i],"ID");
        value= model.getValue(this.data.selectedRecords[i],"VALUE").v;
    }
    }
}
console.log(id);
console.log(value);
```

Can someone advice me?